# Oracle Apex - Set dataSource dynamcally?

Tags: oracle-apex

[image]

Is it possible to set Source of InteractiveGrid dynamically .

Something like :

*if value of  RadioGroup =  "AAA" then IG.Source="Select * from AAA")
else IG.Source="BBB";
refresh IG;*

Answer (score 0):

If it weren't for the **Interactive Grid**, you could use union:

```
select * from aaa where :P1_RADIO_GROUP = 'AAA'
union all
select * from bbb where :P1_RADIO_GROUP = 'BBB'
```

But, although you *can* create an interactive grid region using such a query, it wouldn't work because of

> ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.

error.

---

So, what to do? Maybe the simplest option is to create **two** interactive grid regions, each of them having its own source (`aaa` or `bbb`). Initially (when you run the page), both would be hidden (use dynamic action do do that). Then after you select value of `P1_RADIO_GROUP` item, **show** one of them (using dynamic action, again).

Comment: about the first idea I guess is enough to user "with"  clause. This is a good workaround :)  I will try to implement it . Let you know how  it works.

Comment: about the second one - not suitable in my case .  There are too much logic in this IG and too many other items depends on it .